# How to assign value to local variable in XSLT and be used for next sentence?

Tags: xml, xslt, variable-assignment

Simple things became difficult in XSLT.  Now I don't know how to assign value in XSLT language!

What I wanted to achieve is to get current node value and assign it to a variable @classabbreviation and use it for my next expression.

[image]
Notice I wanted to replace hard coded GENED with expression.

my XML data look like this.

[image]

Comment: getting full description of classes by its abbreviation name

Comment: Please post your code as **code**, not picures.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in XSLT are referenced by using the `$` prefix,not `@` (which serves as a shortcut for the attribute axis).